# Some input subnets in :[!Ref TestRedisSubnetAZ1, !Ref TestRedisSubnetAZ2] are invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I try to create the following CloudFormation stack for a Redis instance (Redis is left out, so just subnet and cache subnet group).
As the title say, the creation of the `TestRedisSubnetGroup` does fail. I can create the subnet group manually with the Console, and I can also create the subnet group when I use the subnet id instead of the `ref` function. I have the subnets already in place, because the stack was created first only with the subnets and now I want to update the stack and add the subnet group. (First approach was to create subnet, group and redis at the same time, but it failed with the same error.)

TL;TR: the `ref` function does not work as expected, what did I wrong?

`vpc-1743447c` is the default VPC with CIDR `172.31.0.0/16`

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: RedisStack
Resources:
  TestRedisSubnetAZ1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: vpc-1743447c
      AvailabilityZone: eu-central-1a
      CidrBlock: 172.31.64.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: TestDeletionPolicyStack-AZ1
  TestRedisSubnetAZ2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: vpc-1743447c
      AvailabilityZone: eu-central-1b
      CidrBlock: 172.31.65.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: TestDeletionPolicyStack-AZ2
  TestRedisSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Test Redis Subnet Group
      SubnetIds:
      - "!Ref TestRedisSubnetAZ1"
      - "!Ref TestRedisSubnetAZ2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `- "!Ref TestRedisSubnetAZ2"` is not valid as a CloudFormation template and `- !Ref TestRedisSubnetAZ2` is not valid YAML. So the alternative way to use the reference is `- Ref: TestRedisSubnetAZ2`. But it is not obvious that `- Ref: TestRedisSubnetAZ2` and `- "Ref: TestRedisSubnetAZ2"` are not the same.

`- Ref: TestRedisSubnetAZ2` is a nested key-value in an array.

```
{
  'SubnetIds' => [
    { 'Ref' => 'TestRedisSubnetAZ1' },
    { 'Ref' => 'TestRedisSubnetAZ2' }
  ]
}
```

---

PS: `DependsOn` is also required to create the stack in one go.